# How can I list all wireless access points and the frequencies use?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, wireless-networking

How can I list all wireless access point stations and the frequencies use?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the software you'll need is [kismet](http://www.kismetwireless.net/), whilst I have done this sort of thing under linux before using this software my main experience is under windows, so I'm afraid I can't be more help.

Answer (score 0):

I use [aircrack-ng](http://www.aircrack-ng.org) for this purpose, but your wireless hardware has to support certain features to fully support all the functionality of the suite. Basic scanning should work with a wider set of hardware.

First you have to put your wireless adapter in monitor mode, first check for available devices:

```
user@host ~ $ sudo airmon-ng

Interface   Chipset     Driver

wlan1       Unknown     iwlwifi - [phy0]
wlan0       Atheros     ath9k - [phy1]
```

then activate monitor mode on one of the interfaces, substitute with one of your devices of course:

```
user@host ~ $ sudo airmon-ng start wlan0


Found 2 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!

PID Name
1628    NetworkManager
1669    wpa_supplicant


Interface   Chipset     Driver

wlan1       Unknown     iwlwifi - [phy0]
wlan0       Atheros     ath9k - [phy1]
            (monitor mode enabled on mon0)
```

You only have to be concerned about warning about interfering processes if your wireless device is set to automatically connect to an access point, either disable the service or he automatic connection in that case.

you can now scan for other wireless clients using the new monitor device `mon0` and `airodump-ng`:

```
user@host ~ $ sudo airodump-ng mon0
```

There are several options to filter the output, check the manpage `man airodump-ng`. If you want to see wireless networks on a certain channel for example you can use

```
user@host ~ $ sudo airodump-ng mon0 -c 6
```

For a list of channels use

```
user@host ~ $ sudo airodump-ng mon0 -c 1,4,11
```

And for a range use

```
user@host ~ $ sudo airodump-ng mon0 -c 4-8
```

The output will look similar to this:

```
BSSID              PWR  Beacons    #Data, #/s  CH  MB   ENC  CIPHER AUTH ESSID

 99:2B:2F:F5:32:88  -79        0        0    0  11  54 . WPA2 CCMP   PSK  Netwrk
 99:0A:F6:C0:E1:70  -61        3        0    0  11  54e. WPA2 CCMP   PSK  Hello
```

In this table the `CH` value represents the channel and at the end is the name of the network using this channel. Check the manpage or website for more information on the other values.

Comment: I know how old the question is, but still had to post the answer as I stumbled across it (thanks to slhck's edit-resurrection).